# Output VRT from 3 tif files is incorrectly georeferenced despite having correct and same CRS

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, georeferencing, vrt, gdalbuildvrt

I have 3 .tif files of a Natural Earth world map, each representing the bands of the source NE world map.

I run `gdalbuildvrt -a_srs EPSG:4326 -separate rgb.vrt red.tif green.tif blue.tif` to create a VRT. The output VRT file is incorrectly placed and its upper left corner is placed exactly the center of the input.tif files.
[image: NE world map .vrt file incorrect location]

However, when I run the same process using a subset of the NE map, the output VRT file is correctly placed. The images are not split in half, I'm just using the Map swipe tool.
[image: NE world map SUBSET .vrt file CORRECT location]

Comment: Looks like your map is not in 4326 - look at the coordinate values (1101,162)

Comment: Yes. But when the cursor is within one of the source RGB .tif files, the coordinates are valid. Only time it goes beyond 180 and 90 is when the cursor is within the output VRT that's not in the lower right quadrant of the source tif file.

Comment: What does gdalinfo show about the coordinate system, extents, and pixel size of red.tif, green.tif, and blue.tif?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/TV5GdG1